# Hide/Show a FormPanel in GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm building a web application with GWT/GAE, and i wanna show a Pop-up to allow user to upload images.

According to [this tutorial](http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/), i need a FormPanel with a FileUpload widget to do the Job. I have extended the Panel and added the proper Widgets, but i don't know how to show the panel when -for example- a user clics a link.

FormPanel javadoc doesn't have a show or hide method, which i used when i worked with PopupPanel or DialogBox. How can i accomplish this in GWT?

PS: I'm not using UIBinder, only plain Java Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the FormPanel as a child to a PopupPanel and DialogBox?

PopupPanel and DialogPanels are HTML absolute divs, attached to the document root, which is why they seem to float freely from the rest of your application. A FormPanel is just a widget and is a div elemen positioned relative to the parent it's attached.